# Make a Bower package using other Bower packages

Tags: bower, bower-install

I'm making a Bower package like Bootstrap but for my own projects. My Bower package is using some other Bower packages, so, I'd like to know how to register a Bower package using other bower packages ?

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should read the [bower.json file specification](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec), and express your dependencies there.